# get plugins used by Jenkins job

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I wrote the following python script to get the list of Jenkins plugins that are used by each Jenkins job.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os

mypath = '/work/jenkins/jobs' for root, subFolders,
files in os.walk(mypath):   if 'config.xml' in files:
      with open(os.path.join(root, 'config.xml'), 'r') as fin:
         for lines in fin:
             if 'plugin=' in lines:
                before_keyword,keyword,after_keyword = lines.partition('plugin=')
                print root,after_keyword
```

It produces the following output for .eg:

```
/work/jenkins/jobs/job1 "subversion@2.2">

/work/jenkins/jobs/job1 "ant@1.2">

/work/jenkins/jobs/job1 "ant@1.2">

/work/jenkins/jobs/job2 "maven-plugin@2.1">

/work/jenkins/jobs/job2 "subversion@2.2">
```

1. Can someone help me tweak my program so that my output looks better?
2. This prints only plugin used by jobs. How can I get plugins used by jenkins systems ( like active directory etc)
3. I would like to copy and paste this output to MS excel with Job in 1 column and plugins used in another column. My output should be easy enough for this transfer.
4. job1 is showing ant@1.2 twice. How can I remove it?
5. job1 and job2 share a common plugin (subversion@2.2). Though I want my initial output to show that( so that I can find which job uses which plugin), I also want another output with these duplicates removed. How can I do this?

UPDATE: I noticed that I could get some of the system plugins used from /work/jenkins/config.xml, but the list is not complete.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Your question is far too broad. You ask for tweaking, pasting to Excel, system wide Jenkins plugins detection, removing double entries.

Comment: To query all plugins, you can try downloading and parsing `http://your.jenkins.url/pluginManager/installed` HTML response.

Comment: The /pluginManager/installed url path requires Admin perms. (You'd be surprised how many people labor under Jenkins servers administered by external departments such as Ops or IT.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### edit:

Here is the code fulfilling the requirements 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5; <del>I couldn't complete the requirement 2 because I don't know how to do that</del> I guess I did it right for the requirement 2, didn't I?:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# coding: utf-8
# Veni Sancte Spiritus

# This code is under public domain.

import os
import argparse
import logging
import re
import openpyxl

logging.basicConfig(
    format="[%(levelname)s]: %(message)s", level=logging.INFO)

try:
    import openpyxl
except ImportError:
    logging.error("Install openpyxl; pip install openpyxl")
    exit(1)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="get plugins used by Jenkins job")
parser.add_argument("--excel", metavar="dir/output1.xslx",
                    help="Output to excel file")

parser.add_argument("--jenkinshome", metavar="/var/lib/jenkins",
                    help="Jenkins home location (default: {})".format(
                        os.getcwd()), default=os.getcwd())

arguments = parser.parse_args()

alreadyadded = []
pluginsalreadyadded = {}

if arguments.excel:
    workbook = openpyxl.Workbook(optimized_write=True)
    worksheet1 = workbook.create_sheet(0, "Output")
    worksheet1.append(["Job name", "Jenkins-CI plugin"])
    worksheet2 = workbook.create_sheet(1, "Output grouping jobs by plugin")
    worksheet2.append(["Jobs", "Jenkins-CI plugin"])
    worksheet3 = workbook.create_sheet(2, "Plugins installed on Jenkins")
    worksheet3.append(["Plugin name", "Plugin version"])

for root, subFolders, files in os.walk(os.path.join(
        arguments.jenkinshome, "jobs")):
    if 'config.xml' in files:
        with open(os.path.join(root, 'config.xml'), 'r') as fin:
            for lines in fin:
                if 'plugin=' in lines:
                    before_keyword, keyword, after_keyword = lines.partition(
                        'plugin=')
                    jobname = os.path.basename(root)
                    plugin = re.sub(r'"(.+)@([0-9.]+)"/?>\n?',
                                    r'\1 ver. \2', after_keyword)

                    if [jobname, plugin] not in alreadyadded:
                        logging.info("{}: {}".format(jobname, plugin))

                        if arguments.excel:
                            worksheet1.append([jobname, plugin])

                            if plugin not in pluginsalreadyadded:
                                pluginsalreadyadded[plugin] = []

                            pluginsalreadyadded[plugin].append(jobname)

                        alreadyadded.append([jobname, plugin])

for root, subFolder, files in os.walk(os.path.join(
        arguments.jenkinshome, "plugins")):
    if "MANIFEST.MF" in files:
        with open(os.path.join(root, "MANIFEST.MF")) as fon:
            name = None
            version = None
            for line in fon:
                if "Extension-Name: " in line:
                    beforekyw, kyw, name = line.partition("Extension-Name: ")
                    # clean the string
                    name = re.search(r'(\w+)', name).group(0)
                elif "Plugin-Version: " in line:
                    beforekyw, kyw, version = line.partition(
                        "Plugin-Version: ")
                    version = re.sub(r'\n', '', version)
                    # clean the string
                    version = re.search(r'(.+)', version).group(0)
            logging.info("{} ver. {}".format(name, version))

            if arguments.excel:
                worksheet3.append([name, version])

if arguments.excel:
    filedest = os.path.expanduser(arguments.excel)
    filedest = os.path.abspath(filedest)
    path = os.path.dirname(filedest)
    if not os.path.isdir(path):
        os.makedirs(path)

    # write output for worksheet2
    for plugin, jobs in pluginsalreadyadded.iteritems():
        worksheet2.append([" | ".join(jobs), plugin])

    # save the file
    workbook.save(filedest)
```

Here, This is the output:

```
<(jorge@abril)---(mar may 13 14:30:25)>
[recetario][59] $ ./jenkins-plugins.py --jenkinshome /var/lib/jenkins --excel hoja.xslx
[INFO]: Robert S. - Music metadata from Amazon (Windows build): mercurial ver. 1.50
[INFO]: Robert S. - Music metadata from Amazon (Windows build): jclouds-jenkins ver. 2.5.1
[INFO]: Robert S. - Music metadata from Amazon (Windows build): gcm-notification ver. 1.0
[INFO]: Robert S. - Music metadata from Amazon (Windows build): instant-messaging ver. 1.28
[INFO]: Robert S. - playcomscrap: mercurial ver. 1.50
[INFO]: Robert S. - playcomscrap: shiningpanda ver. 0.20
[INFO]: Robert S. - playcomscrap: gcm-notification ver. 1.0
[INFO]: Robert S. - playcomscrap: instant-messaging ver. 1.28
[INFO]: Robert S. - 419742: mercurial ver. 1.49
[INFO]: Robert S. - Scrap Game Product Information (Windows build): mercurial ver. 1.50
[INFO]: playcomscrap - construye instalable: mercurial ver. 1.50
[INFO]: playcomscrap - construye instalable: gcm-notification ver. 1.0
[INFO]: playcomscrap - construye instalable: instant-messaging ver. 1.28
[INFO]: Robert S. - Scrap Game Product Information (Unit tests): mercurial ver. 1.50
[INFO]: Robert S. - Scrap Game Product Information (Unit tests): shiningpanda ver. 0.20
[INFO]: Danny L. - FLICK 2: mercurial ver. 1.50
[INFO]: jabber ver. 1.25
[INFO]: emotional ver. 1.1
[INFO]: cvs ver. 2.11
[INFO]: mailer ver. 1.8
[INFO]: jclouds ver. 2.5.1
[INFO]: matrix ver. 1.2
[INFO]: python ver. 1.2
[INFO]: compact ver. 1.10
[INFO]: pam ver. 1.1
[INFO]: ldap ver. 1.9
[INFO]: xvfb ver. 1.0.10
[INFO]: mailcommander ver. 1.0.0
[INFO]: ant ver. 1.2
[INFO]: ssh ver. 1.6.1
[INFO]: ssh ver. 1.6
[INFO]: credentials ver. 1.10
[INFO]: jira ver. 1.39
[INFO]: gcm ver. 1.0
[INFO]: libvirt ver. 1.8.4
[INFO]: scm ver. 0.2
[INFO]: subversion ver. 2.3
[INFO]: external ver. 1.2
[INFO]: antisamy ver. 1.1
[INFO]: shiningpanda ver. 0.20
[INFO]: publish ver. 1.11
[INFO]: windows ver. 1.0
[INFO]: maven ver. 2.3
[INFO]: instant ver. 1.28
[INFO]: mercurial ver. 1.50
[INFO]: xvnc ver. 1.14
[INFO]: javadoc ver. 1.1
[INFO]: translation ver. 1.11
[INFO]: matrix ver. 1.2
[INFO]: xunit ver. 1.88
[INFO]: postbuild ver. 1.8
[INFO]: jquery ver. 1.7.2-1

<(jorge@abril)---(mar may 13 14:30:27)>
[recetario][60] $
```

This is how it looks the excel file:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Yes, the second output seems ugly, bu that is because I couldn't make the cell value of many lines as needed because at the moment of opening the file, the last job name was the value of the cell, thus, I separate every job name with a `|`.

Use the `--help` command for... well, you should know what that command does :). **You need to install `openpyxl`** because this module is required to write the output into a Excel file.